# External memory vs. heap memory in node.js - any tradeoffs one way or the other?

Tags: node.js, arrays, memory-management

In node.js, what is the difference between memory allocated in the node.js heap vs. memory reported as "external" as seen in [`process.memoryUsage()`](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_memoryusage)?  As there advantages or disadvantages to one over the other?  If you were going to have a particularly large object (gigabytes), does it matter which one is used?  That doc only says this:

> external refers to the memory usage of C++ objects bound to JavaScript
> objects managed by V8.

It doesn't tell you what any consequences or tradeoffs might be of doing allocations that use this "external" memory instead of the heap memory.

I'm examining tradeoffs between using a large Array (regular Javascript Array object) vs. a large Uint32Array object.  Apparently, an Array is always allocated in the heap, but a Uint32Array is always allocated from "external" memory (not in the heap).

Here the background.  I have an object that needs a fairly large array of 32 bit integers as part of what it does.  This array can be as much as a billion units long.  I realized that I could cut the storage occupied by the array in half if I switched to a Uint32Array instead of a regular Array because a regular Array stores things as double precision floats (64 bits long) vs. a Uint32Array stores things as 32 bit values.

In a test jig, I measured that the Uint32Array does indeed use 1/2 the total storage for the same number of units long (32-bits per unit instead of 64-bits per unit).  But, when looking at the results of [`process.memoryUsage()`](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_memoryusage), I noticed that the Uint32Array storage is in the "external" bucket of storage whereas the array is in the "heapUsed" bucket of storage.

To add to the context a bit more, because a Uint32Array is not resizable, when I do need to change its size, I have to allocate a new Uint32Array and then copy data over from the original (which I suppose could lead to more memory fragmentation opportunites).  With an Array, you can just change the size and the JS engine takes care of whatever has to happen internally to adjust to the new size.

What are the advantages/disadvantages of making a large storage allocation that's "external" vs. in the "heap"?   Any reason to care?

Comment: Does this answer your question? - https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/396963/so-fails-to-promote-well-researched-well-written-but-difficult-questions

Comment: @bravemaster - I don't understand your reference there.  Are you suggesting that this is a well researched, difficult question that is getting no attention like what that meta discussion is talking about?  Or that this is not a well researched question?  Or that I should follow various techniques referenced there to try to draw more attention to the question?  I'm confused what you mean by that reference.

Comment: Definitely the first point, and maybe third, yes.

Comment: @bravemaster - I just concluded that it's a question that very, very few people know anything about and it would just be luck if one of that small population of people actually wandered into this question.  I was hoping that either more people knew about it or for a chance encounter with the small number of people who do, but I guess it didn't happen.

Comment: You could ask Ryan Dahl personally, but maybe he forgot it. Since he is into Deno right now :)

Answer (score 0):

The heap is for pure JavaScript objects such as Arrays, Objects, strings, etc. It is garbage-collection managed space and supports all of the various other types all mixed together. The external space, as you saw, is for binary data. You can use it for other things (e.g. sending data between worker threads) image processing, etc.

It's useful to think of the various TypedArrays as blocks of contiguous binary data in memory, whereas JS Arrays are going to be stored as some other structure. This is a big part of why they would have a larger in-memory footprint. You don't get things like push, pop, shift, or resizing with TypedArrays because you are essentially just working with a strip of memory and access is just index * int size.

If you know you are only going to be storing 32bit ints, something like an Uint32Array makes sense, you don't need a standard Array because it doesn't need to additionally have the flexibility to suddenly store a randomly shaped object in addition to all of those integers.